# How do I Read and Write data from a USB stick?

Tags: arduino-uno, usb

Hello I have an Arduino Uno and I salvaged a USB port from an old computer. The USB port has 4 pins on it and it accepts USB sticks. I was wondering if it is possible to connect it to my Arduino so my Arduino can load data from files on the USB. I don't want to go out and buy a shield but I don't mind using libraries. Is it possible to read and write data from a USB stick with Arduino?

Comment: Usb OTG mass storage library. Good luck

Comment: Requires an USB Host Shield. The UNO can only work as device otherwise. Talking to a stick requires host role.

Answer (score 2):

The Uno does not have any USB ***host*** or OTG capabilities on its own, and bit banging it is not easy. A USB Host shield, or a better microcontroller is needed.